# ASP.NET Core + Framework in IIS getting HTTP 404

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Ok - this is my first deployment of an ASP.NET Core app.  One wrinkle to keep in mind is that I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and targeting Framework version 4.6.2 (not .Net Core).  It all runs fine on my local machine with VS2017 and IISExpress.

I went through the procedure outlined by MS here: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  The documentation is long and complicated, but I think I covered everything.  It makes one thing clear: **The in-process hosting model isn't supported for ASP.NET Core apps that target the .NET Framework.**  So, I know I need to use Out-of-Proc.
Some other points:

- I published the app to a local folder and copied it to the server without any changes.
- I created the new app in the Default Web Site and gave it its own app pool - set as "No Managed Code"
- Out-of-proc is the default, so I have not done any special config for this.
- I have confirmed that AspNetCoreModuleV2 appears in the list of Modules.

**The Result**

Every page I hit I get HTTP404.  I am running IE locally on the server and using a URL like: http://localhost/MyApp/Home/MyView

- The application pool shows having 1 application running.
- The App Event Log shows a message like: Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/MyApp' started process '8864' successfully and process '8864' is listening on port '37706'.  It shows no errors.
- I have tried adding a default.htm file to the root of the app and loading the static page directly (using http://localhost/MyApp/default.htm).  This gives 404.  If I remove the web.config, this page will load.

I really didn't expect deploying the app to be this complicated.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to troubleshoot or fix this problem?

**Update 1**: Web.config is below.  I have tried with and without hostModel=...  aspNetCore logs show successful startup.  Nothing is added to the log with each page access attempt (seems weird)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="JavaScript" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="CSS" path="*.css" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\My.App.Name.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess">
      <environmentVariables />
      <handlerSettings>
        <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="file" />
        <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value="d:\Log\MyApp.log" />
      </handlerSettings>
    </aspNetCore> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: ee76911e-decb-48b7-bd74-36ebfbdb22b6-->
```

Comment: what happens if you just hit the default controller @http://localhost/MyApp? Also, could post your web.config of the deployed app.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture http headers on working machine.  Then compare the headers on non working machine.  You have a credential issue and the headers may not be the same on machines.  For example the default Browser may be different and the code isn't designed to work with a different Browser.  A certificate may be missing.  The http may be using 1.1 (chunk mode) instead of 1.0 stream mode.

Comment: If I hit http://localhost/MyApp, I also get 404.  I'll research the other suggestion - thanks.

Comment: In process explorer I see svchost.exe>w3wp.exe>My.App.Name.exe>conhost.exe as a task>subtask tree.  Shouldn't I see dotnet.exe in there if I am hosting out-of-process?

Comment: @shindigo Have you tried hosting your webapp as a separate website in IIS rather than as an application under Default Website?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  I was making use of the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable, but was unaware that the publish process does not put this in web.config.  I added this to Web.config:

```
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

and the pages now load.

The most useful diagnostics I found were at this link [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  There they recommended that I run My.App.Name.exe from the command prompt.  This creates a web process and assigns it to a port and gives you all the console output.  This allowed me to figure out it was actually half working and that led me to the fact that I was missing the Env Variable.

Thanks again for the suggestions...